# PHPBB3 notification email to admins on new user registration

Tags: php, registration, bots, spam, phpbb

Most of the mods I have found online are for approving registration, but I don't need that. Simply when a new user registers, admin will get email. I have setup a pretty good anti spam mod that is very effective but still from time to time a bot slips through. Since this is a growing forum I need admin to get notified of new registration, so he can check if it is a bot or not.

Also if there is no mod that can do this, I will code it myself, in that case a tip from what file I should get started would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't part of core phpBB functionality and cannot be easily enabled in the administration. I wrote a MOD for it about six years ago, it's marked abandoned now, but it might still work (or there could be hints in the discussion what needs to be fixed).

https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=583923